# gamemenu variable will not update

Tags: swift, terminal

gamerule will not update, I've checked and the variables inside it do but gamerule itself doesn't. it was working at one point but I changed some code and now it doesn't, though it should be after reviewing everything.

```
import Foundation

print(
    """
  ╔═════# menu #═════╗
  
    --  play (p)
    --  settings (s)
  
  ╚══════════════════╝
  """)

var stats = [100, 100, 100]
var y = 1
var x = 0
//map
var level_1 = ["□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□",]
var level_2 = ["□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□",]
var level_3 = ["□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□", "□",]
func type(i: Int) {
    let line_array = [
        "it begins . . . ", //0
        "input a valid option : ", //1
        "exited inventory. ", //2
        "no items in inventory. ", //3
        "item found: ", //4
        "nothing found. ", //5
        "choose move direction. ", //6
        "input an action: " //7"
    ]
    
    for char in line_array[i]  {
        print(char, terminator: "")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1)
        fflush(stdout)
    }
}

func change_pos() {
    if y == 1 {
        level_1[x] = "▪"
    }
    else if y == 2 {
        level_2[x] = "▪"
    }
    else if y == 3{
        level_3[x] = "▪"
    }
    print(y, level_1)
}



// game
var gamemenu = ("""

╔══════# stats #══════╗ ╔═# actions #═╗ ╔═════# map #═════╗
  health: \(stats[0])              items (i)       \(level_3)
  thirst: \(stats[1])              search (s)      \(level_2)
  hunger: \(stats[2])              move (m)        \(level_1)
╚═════════════════════╝ ╚═════════════╝ ╚═════════════════╝

""")
// <--- negative x | 0 (starting) | positive x --->

//inventory
var items = [String]()
var weight = 0.0
var max = 30.0

//search
var obj = Int()
let objects = ["bat", "knife", "hammer", "axe", "fists"]

//func if_or(o_1: String, o_2: String) -> Bool { //option = o
//   var o = 0
// if let action = readLine() {
//    if action.lowercased() == o_1 || action.lowercased() == o_2 {
//      return true
//}
//}
//}

func play() {
    type(i: 0)
    sleep(1)
    
    let replacements = ["\"", "[", "]", ","]
    for replacement in replacements {
        gamemenu = gamemenu.replacingOccurrences(of: replacement, with: "")
    }
    print(gamemenu)
    actions()
    
}

func menu() {
    if let status = readLine() {
        if status.lowercased() == "play" || status.lowercased() == "p" {
            play()
        } else if status.lowercased() == "settings" || status.lowercased() == "s" {
            print("settings")
        } else {
            type(i: 1)
        }
        menu()
    }
}


func actions() {
    
    type(i: 7)
    if let action = readLine() {
        if action.lowercased() == "i" || action.lowercased() == "items" {
            inventory()
        } else if action.lowercased() == "s" || action.lowercased() == "search" {
            search()
        } else if action.lowercased() == "m" || action.lowercased() == "move" {
            move()
        } else {
            type(i: 1)
        }
        actions()
    }
}

func move() {
    type(i: 6)
    print("""

  northwest   north   northeast
            ⇖   ↑   ⇗
        west ←     → east
            ⇙   ↓   ⇘
  southwest   south   southeast
""")
    if let action = readLine() {
        if action.lowercased() == "north" {
            y += 1
            change_pos()
            print(y)
            sleep(1)
            print(gamemenu)
            actions()
        } else if action.lowercased() == "northeast" {
            y += 1
            x += 1
            change_pos()
            print(gamemenu)
            actions()
        }
    }
}


func search_s() {
    obj = Int.random(in: 1...8)
    if obj == 1 {
        type(i: 4)
        sleep(1)
        obj = Int.random(in: 0...3)
        print(objects[obj])
        items.append(objects[obj])
        print(gamemenu)
        actions()
    } else {
        type(i: 5)
        sleep(1)
        print(gamemenu)
        actions()
    }
}

func search() {
    if y == 1 {
        level_1[x] = "▨"
        search_s()
    } else if y == 2 {
        level_2[x] = "▨"
        search_s()
    } else {
        level_3[x] = "▨"
        search_s()
    }
}

func inventory() {
    print("""

╔═# inventory #═╗
""")
    
    for item in items {
        print(item)
    }
    
    print("""
 wt. : \(weight)/30.0
 discard (d)
 exit (e)
╚═══════════════╝
""")
    if let action = readLine() {
        if action.lowercased() == "d" || action.lowercased() == "discard" {
            if items.isEmpty == true {
                type(i: 3)
            }
            sleep(1)
            inventory()
        } else if action.lowercased() == "e" || action.lowercased() == "exit" {
                type(i: 2)
        } else {
            print("insert index (0...)")
            if let invread = readLine() {
                if let discard = Int(invread) {
                    items.remove(at: discard)
                    print("successfully removed item")
                    print(gamemenu)
                    actions()
                }
            }
        sleep(1)
        print(gamemenu)
        actions()
    }
    }
}
change_pos()
menu()
```

I've no clue what to do really, I've tried checked if the variables have changed and they've, except they don't display so.

Comment: gamemenu is a variable but you never update it. I moved the code (the actual string) into a function and called that function to initialise the variable and then also the code that moves north and I got an updated map printed so maybe start there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.